# How can i use jquery to validate a field that should be filled with integers only?

Tags: jquery

My entire project submission is pending only because of this one issue.I have used all validation in jquery form so that i could be fast and good for the use but i am stuck in this.could you please help me out in this issue.

Comment: I'm all done but submission is pending because I see no code supplied from your side.

Answer (score 0):

Try the jQuery validate plugin : http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/number

Answer (score 0):

I handled this issue in 2 ways.

1) User can enter characters also but on submission time user will get alert like 'Value should be a numeric'

2) Not allow user to enter character in text field

Example is http://jsfiddle.net/2dJAN/25/

```
<input type="text" id ="fax_field" name="fax_field"/>



$("#fax_field").keyup(function(event) {
        var limitField = $(this).val().trim().length;
        this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9_\-\.]/g, '');    
});
```