# Required field that should be filled only with integers

Tags: jquery

I am working upon validation of a field where in the field should be filled only with integers and validation that the field is needed is also given?

I inserted the script tags as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.numeric.js"></script>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
$("#estvalue").numeric({
negative: false 
}, 
function() {
alert("No negative values");
this.value = "";
this.focus(); });
});
  </script>
<input name="Est_Value" id="estvalue" class="regi_input_1" style="width: 150px; height: 25px;" type="text" />
```

Comment: He posted 3  same kind questiong within  2 hrs

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16538303/i-want-my-field-to-accept-only-integers-and-i-have-kept-that-field-in-required-v

Comment: @PSR Yep. I am closing his other questions.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16539288/how-can-i-use-jquery-to-validate-a-field-that-should-be-filled-with-integers-onl

Comment: @saika why you are posted these many times

Comment: Take a look at the related question.

[How to enforce only numeric values in textbox][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/995183/how-to-allow-only-numeric-0-9-in-html-inputbox-using-jquery

Answer (score 0):

## **USE HTML5**

```
<input type="number" min="0" />


<input name="Est_Value" id="estvalue" class="regi_input_1" style="width: 150px; height: 25px;" type="number" min="0" />
```

## **Validation Using  JavaScript**

```
<input name="Est_Value" id="estvalue" class="regi_input_1" style="width: 150px; height: 25px;" type="text" onkeypress="if ( isNaN( String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode) )){ alert('numbers only'); return false; }" />
```

Working Demo http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/FEVrB/

Comment: He posted 3  same kind questiong within  2 hrs

Comment: if i'm using number type in my code then i'm getting a selection box, thanks for giving me some new idea but at present i dont want it i just want if anyone enters a variable a error msg should appear